# Highlight specific paired data in ggpaired plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am comparing paired samples across two timepoints. I would like to highlight a specific sample by changing the color of the points and line to red in order to show how certain samples increase over time.
The data, df, consists of 10 samples with two timepoints and I want to highlight point D because it has a large increase.

| ID | Time1 | Time2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.296 | 0.083 |
| B | 0.184 | 0.300 |
| C | 0.523 | 0.703 |
| D | 0.301 | 1.458 |
| E | 1.089 | 0.511 |
| F | 0.016 | 0.313 |
| G | 1.502 | 1.701 |
| H | 0.101 | 0.727 |
| I | 0.290 | 0.212 |
| J | 0.719 | 0.921 |

I generated a paired box plot using the ggpaired() function.
[ggpaired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS0YM.jpg)

```
ggpaired(df, cond1 = "Time1", cond2 = "Time2", line.color = "gray", fill = "condition", palette = "jco", xlab = "Sample Timepoint", ylab = "OD") +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(colour = "Black", size = 14, face = "bold.italic"))
```

I have tried to overlay a separate ggpaired plot using the subsetting sample of interest but it will not work for me.

```
ggpaired(df, cond1 = "Time1", cond2 = "Time2", line.color = "gray", fill = "condition", palette = "jco", xlab = "Sample Timepoint", ylab = "OD") +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(colour = "Black", size = 14, face = "bold.italic")) + 
  ggpaired(test, cond1 = "Time1", cond2 = "Time2", line.color = "red", fill = "condition", palette = "jco", xlab = "Sample Timepoint", ylab = "OD")
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Or am I better off just adding a separate line graph. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I get it from the docs `ggpaired` only offers the option to set the color for all lines as an argument. But if you want to highlight just some IDs you could do so using a `geom_line` to which you pass a subsetted dataframe:

```
ggpaired(df,
  cond1 = "Time1", cond2 = "Time2", line.color = "gray",
  fill = "condition", palette = "jco", xlab = "Sample Timepoint", ylab = "OD"
) +
  geom_line(data = ~subset(., ID %in% c("A", "B")), aes(group = id), color = "red") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(colour = "Black", size = 14, face = "bold.italic"))
```

[image]